# Angle between vectors from the angle between projections

Tags: geometry

In $3$D, project two unit vectors onto a plane spanned by two other vectors. If we know the angle between the projections, what will be the possible angles between the original vectors?

Answer (score 1):

Obviously it's not possible. Consider the vectors $(1,0,2)$, $(1,0,1)$. Their projection on the plane $XY$ are the vectors $(1,0,0)$ and $(1,0,0)$. They have the same projection, so the angle between their projections is $0$, from which you can't obviously recover the angle between the original vectors. All the vectors $(1,0,z)$ projects onto $(1,0,0)$, so all the information about angles between them is lost in the projection.

Answer (score 0):

It could be anything with normal angle ranges $(0,180°)$

[image: fig]

The two vectors might be near perpendicular to the projection plane and their angle be 0 or 180, or the vectors might be parallel to the projection plane and their angle equals the angle specified in the question $\psi$.

Answer (score -1):

You can assume that the plane is the $xy$, and you can take the projections as vectors $P_1 = (x_1, y_1, 0)$ and $P_2 = (x_2, y_2, 0)$

The original vectors will be

$ V_1 =  P_1 + z_1 k $

$ V_2 = P_2 + z_2 k $

The angle between them $\phi$ satisfies

$ \cos \phi = \dfrac{ P_1 \cdot P_2 + z_1 z_2 }{ \sqrt{ \| P_1 \|^2 + z_1^2} \sqrt{ \| P_2 \|^2 + z_2^2}} $

Now the angle between the projections $\theta$ satisfies

$ \cos \theta = \dfrac{ P_1 \cdot P_2 }{ \| P_1 \| \| P_2 \| } $

Using this in the expression for $\cos \phi$, we get

$\cos \phi = \dfrac{ \cos \theta \|P_1\| \| P_2\| + z_1 z_2 }{\sqrt{ \| P_1 \|^2 + z_1^2} \sqrt{ \| P_2 \|^2 + z_2^2}} $

Dividing top and bottom by $ \|P_1\| \|P_2 \| $ results in

$\cos \phi = \dfrac{ \cos \theta  + u_1 u_2 }{\sqrt{ 1 + u_1^2} \sqrt{ 1 + u_2^2}} $

where $u_1 = \dfrac{z_1}{\|P_1\|} , u_2 = \dfrac{z_2}{\| P_2 \|} $

Taking the limit as $u_1 \to \infty$ gives

$\displaystyle \lim_{u_1 \to \infty} \cos \phi = \dfrac{u_2}{\sqrt{1 + u_2^2 } } $

And similarly for $u_2 \to \infty$.  One can see that the limit if both $u_1$ and $u_2$ tend to infinity is $\cos \phi = 1 $ , i.e. $\phi_\infty = 0$

If $u_1 \to \infty$ while $u_2 \to -\infty$ then $\cos \phi \to -1$ , i.e. $\phi \to \pi $.